# Random value of a user-defined data Type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random, functional-programming, deriving

I've defined the following Data Type:

```
data NewBool = Truth | Lie deriving (Show)
```

and I've created a function which should return a random NewBool-value

```
giveMeBool :: IO()
giveMeBool = do 
     bool <- randomIO :: IO NewBool
     putStrLn("Your random boolean is"++ show bool)
```

I've read here that I have to make NewBool an instance of Random to use randomIO. So I've done this:

```
 instance Random NewBool where
 random g = case random g of
              (r,g')  | r < (1/2)= (Truth, g')
                      | otherwise= (Lie, g')
```

Sincerely it's just a copy&paste of what I've found in another post, but I don't understand exactly how it works? How is the value and Type of r defined? Can anyone help me? Thanks ;)

Comment: You are aware that there's a `Random Bool` instance?

Answer (score 6):

Since `random` has the type (essentially)

```
random :: Random a => StdGen -> (a, StdGen)
```

if you pass it the `StdGen` you have, `g`, it'll give you a value of any type instantiating the `Random` type. The compiler guesses at what type you need by how you use it. In your case, it gets used in the fragment

```
r < (1/2)
```

and we can examine the types of each of these pieces

```
(<)   :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
(1/2) :: Fractional a => a
```

which together imply that the full type of `r` is

```
r :: (Random a, Fractional a, Ord a) => a
```

This isn't enough yet for Haskell to proceed, but since this is a common enough situation in numeric types (since numeric literals resolve to ambiguous types, not concrete numeric types) Haskell has a "defaulting" system. In particular, the following `default` configuration is in effect (by default)

```
default (Integer, Double)
```

which means that if you have an ambiguous type, constrained by classes, and either `Integer` or `Double` can satisfy those classes then, in that order, these concrete types are substituted in. In the case of `r`, `Double` instantiates `Random`, `Ord`, and `Fractional` so the compiler picks `r :: Double`.

Finally, we consider the `Random` instance for `Double` which just so happens to pick random `Double` values on the interval `(0,1)`. This means that there's a 50% chance of it being greater than `(1/2)` and thus each of the `Truth` and `Lie` constructors will be chosen with equal odds.

---

Finally, for really implementing `Random NewBool` it's possibly better to bootstrap the instance off the very similar instance available with `Bool`.

```
instance Random NewBool where
  random g = case random g of
    (True,  g') -> (Truth, g')
    (False, g') -> (Lie,   g')
```

though this only works if you don't want to modify the behavior of the random generator from that of `Random Bool`. However, take note that a similar type resolution is occurring here—except it's far simplified since I'm matching on patterns `True` and `False` which immediately mean that the return type of `random g` *must* be `(Bool, StdGen)`.

Comment: I would mention that a minimal complete definition also needs `randomR`. But that can also be bootstrapped.